# Current upload step from aiohhtp post

Tags: python, aiohttp

I'm wondering how I can get the current Upload step from the aiohttp `post` method. Usually I would use the `get` method to pull the current step in a loop but this doesn't work if the host doesn't response the current upload step. So it is possible to get the current step? Something like "upload from xx% are almost done". I mean it is very annoying to wait until the upload is completed

```
async def post_task():
    archive =  open("file")
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    post = await session.post("upload_url", data=archive, ssl = False)
    await post.read()
    await session.close()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(post_task())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use [streaming uploads](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#streaming-uploads) in combination with [`tqdm.asyncio`](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/asyncio/) to track the progress of the file upload.

More or less from the streaming uploads documentation:

```py
import asyncio
import os.path

import aiofiles as aiofiles
import aiohttp as aiohttp
from tqdm.asyncio import tqdm


async def file_sender(file_name, chunksize):
    async with aiofiles.open(file_name, "rb") as f:
        chunk = await f.read(chunksize)
        while chunk:
            yield chunk
            chunk = await f.read(chunksize)


def upload_with_progress(file_name=None, chunksize=64 * 1024):
    size = os.path.getsize(file_name)
    return tqdm(file_sender(file_name, chunksize), total=size // chunksize)


# Then you can use file_sender as a data provider:
async def post_task():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(
            "upload_url",
            data=upload_with_progress("file"),
            ssl=False,
        ) as resp:
            print(await resp.text())


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(post_task())
```

Comment: When I try to upload a .tar file I get ```RuntimeError: cannot schedule new futures after shutdown```. I'm not sure how I solve that. May you have the problem?